# How to create a magnetic map using the magnetometer of the smartphone?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have a   magnetometer, and I would like to know how to plot a map of the readings. We have the magnitudes in Nano Tesla of the X, Y, and Z axis.

Comment: You may have a look on the faq about asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

You may need to schedule periodic updates by using AlarmManager, or Handler.postDelayed (timer), every time querying values from your sensor and Coordinates from LocationManager. Then save time, sensor readings and coordinates to database (it is better to use Realm). The last part- when measuring is done, read all values from database and convert those to some format (perhaps, Json in text file), so you can transfer this file on your pc for further processing (interpolation, etc)